# gunzip multiple archives to specific folder

Tags: bash, archiving, gunzip

is there possibility to gunzip multiple files into one folder?

I have alot of access logs which I need to exctract do folder. There placed in `/var/log/nginx/` and they are named like `access.log.2.gz` 
But there is tricky one .. I need all archives from that folder from one specific month.

There is alot of this access logs and I need them extract in to directory `/var/log/nginx/target`

I already tested

```
for f in *.gz; do
  STEM=$(access.log. "${f}" .gz)
  gunzip -c "${f}" > /var/log/nginx/target/"${STEM}"
done
```

But not worked at all..

Comment: Why not just "gunzip *"  to unzip each of the files ? A file called access.log.XX.gz should unzip to access.log.XX   - and the wildcard should allow you to process all the files at once.

Comment: There is about 60 log files, each from differend date, I need only from June .. thats why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code, I believe, is most likely the calculation of STEM.  Its not immediately clear to me the format that your files are in or how you are going to group them, but try something like:

```
# Find files created within date range:
fromdate="201606010000"
todate="201606302359"
touch -t $fromdate /tmp/fromdate.del
touch -t $todate /tmp/todate.del

# Extract only the desired files to destination, removing the .gz extension
for f in `find /var/log/nginx/*.gz  -type f -newer $fromdate ! -newer $todate`
do
     zcat $f > /var/log/ngiz/target/${f::-3}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not know which logs contain June:

```
zcat *gz | grep Jun > junelog
```